# Only getting certain json data based on jQuery get and values

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following code

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'api/api.php?getPosts&lat=' + latitude + '&long=' + longitude + '',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = $.parseJSON(data, true);
                    $.each(result, function(key,value) {
                        $('.grid').append('<div class="box"><div class="box-content"><img src="assets/memes/' + value.post_content + '" class="image"><div class="caption">' + value.caption + '</div><div class="caption">' + value.distance + '</div></div></div>');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Which returns a bunch of data and a value distance and displays on page. I want to calculate the distance and only show items that have distance value of 0-100 instead of just showing them all.

Currently the get returns something like

```
{"id":8,"post_content":"root-1440568030.gif","caption":"thisisatest","timestamp":1440568030,"collectable":1,"expire_time":2,"distance":1.1118957717237}
```

I want to only show the items that have  distance value of 0-100 on the page

Comment: What's the problem? Don't you know how to write an `if` statement inside the `.each` function?

Comment: if `value.distance<=100` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code above, the line

```
$('.grid').append('<div class="box"><div class="box-content"><img src="assets/memes/' + value.post_content + '" class="image"><div class="caption">' + value.caption + '</div><div class="caption">' + value.distance + '</div></div></div>');
```

Is handling what renders your results.

To only show the ones with a distance value between `0` and `100` you can wrap this line in and `if` statement.

```
if ((value.distance >= 0) && (value.distance <= 100)) {
    $('.grid').append('<div class="box"><div class="box-content"><img src="assets/memes/' + value.post_content + '" class="image"><div class="caption">' + value.caption + '</div><div class="caption">' + value.distance + '</div></div></div>');
}
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Why call `parseInt` when `value.distance` is already a number?

Answer (score 0):

Use `if`.

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {
    if (value.distance >= 0 && value.distance <= 100) {
        $('.grid').append(...);
    }
});
```

If distances can never be negative, you don't need the `value.distance >= 0 &&` part.